# Http POST + auth using Apache async http client

Tags: java, json, authentication, post

I am doing a asynchronous http request to a web service. I am not that sure if this is the correct way to do it but it works.

Is this the correct way to make POST + authentication with HttpAsyncClient?

Should I close the httpclient at the end with httpclient.close(); ?

```
public void asyncHttpRequest() {
    try {            

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(3000)
                .setConnectTimeout(3000).build();
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();

        httpclient.start();

        String postParameter = new JSONObject().put("key", "value").toString(); //Creating JSON string

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.url.com");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(postParameter));
        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds
                = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
        httpPost.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, httpPost, null));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        httpclient.execute(httpPost, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {

                try {
                    InputStream responseBody = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    String serverResponse = IOUtils.toString(responseBody);

                    System.out.println("Server response : " + serverResponse);
                    System.out.println(httpPost.getRequestLine() + "->" + response.getStatusLine());

                } catch (IOException | UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
                    //Do something
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void failed(final Exception ex) {
                //Do something
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {
                //Do something
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //Do something
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check here? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a credentials provider like below, instead of explicitly adding a header for basic authentication:

```
CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, creds);

CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
            .build();
```

Also, it would be best to explicitly close the httpclient after the request has been completely processed.

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Unfortunately this way it is not authenticating. I get 401 response.
Also the service documentation states that the authentication should be done via header.

Comment: The header required for HTTP Basic Authentication should have been added automatically using the code above. It might help to take a look at the HTTP request wire log. You can enable it as described here - http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html